# Http Request in AsyncTask Causes OutofMemory Error on Multiple Screen Rotations

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-asynctask, rotation

I am a new Android programmer. My first major task was to create an Http Post request which runs in an AsyncTask in a fragment.

I have spent well over a hundred hours learning the ins and outs of AsyncTask and its many flaws and quirks. I have read hundreds of pages, performed hundreds of Google searches and read tens of thousands of words in an attempt to solve this issue. I have examined EVERY. SINGLE. TINY. ASPECT. of my code, removing and replacing it tiny piece by tiny piece, often line by line, and debugging, attempting to figure out what is going on here. All I have discovered is a burning dislike for Android and the methodologies behind it.

I create an activity. Lets call it "Login". I then create a fragment. Let's call it "LoginTaskFragment". When a user taps a button, the fragment runs the AsyncTask, which executes a request to a url. If the response takes a long while (I add a sleep into the script on the server side to simulate this), and the user rotates the screen over and over again, at some point, the app will crash, returning an Out of Memory error.

This happens if I run the task in a UI-less fragment or UI fragment. It happens even though I call setRetainInstance(true). I have checked and I am 100 percent positive that the AsyncTask is NOT being re-run on screen rotation. Now, if I remove the Http Post request entirely, I do not have the issue (or perhaps the memory leak is too small to have an effect, even after over a hundred rotations, which I've tried). The problem still occurs even if I call asyncTask.cancel(false) ... or true ... in onStop. Using the WeakReference trick mentioned often alongside AsyncTasks in many tutorials makes no difference whatsoever.

I am also using the savedInstanceState Bundle in the activity to save certain pertinent data in the activity itself, and I am not entirely clear if this affects the fragment's asynctask lifetime. But my understanding is not.

Honestly, I feel that this is ridiculous and should not be an issue. At all. Since Android happily destroys your objects on screen rotation, it should happily be responsible with GC as well, but of course, we all know, it's not. It seems to be a patchwork, bandaid-ed joke.

Here is some code where I initialize the fragment in the activity:

```
LoginTaskFragment loginFieldsTask = new LoginTaskFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(loginFieldsTask,"loginFieldsTask").commit();
```

Here is the relevant fragment code. If I strip out EVERYTHING, and just leave this, I have the problem, regardless of anything else in my code:

```
...
protected JsonObject doInBackground(Void... params) {

String postUrl="<some nice url here>";

ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "un"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "pw"));

HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 30000);

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postUrl);
try {

     httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
     HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
     httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
     String json = reader.readLine();

     JsonElement jElement = new JsonParser().parse(json);
     JsonObject jObject = jElement.getAsJsonObject();

     return jObject;

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
     httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
} catch (IOException e) {
     httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
} catch (Exception e) {
     httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}

return null;

}
```

I know that if I set the socket timeout to a low number, it DOES seem to kill the thread and I can rotate to my heart's content. But I would like to leave the timeout at 30 seconds as in the code above to allow for older phone network connectivity problems.

My understanding is that since the thread is in a fragment, it SHOULD NOT BE RECREATED when the screen rotates. And this seems to be true. onCreate is definitely not being called on rotation.

This is the line at which everything hinges on, of course:

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I can't believe no one has had this exact problem, but after over a hundred hours searching and slamming my head against the wall, I've had enough. I need someone better than me at this to tell me what's going on.

**Edit:** Adding android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" is not a good idea, and is heavily discouraged for this use as bad practice. See [Handling the Configuration Change Yourself here]. In fact, this is the whole point of using a UI-less fragment in the first place. The AsyncTask fragment is NEVER destroyed until the task within is complete. It is thus never recreated despite the fact that underlying activity IS being recreated over and over.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`
in your fragment class to limit the rotation so that it will not re-execute the code when the rotation occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to recreate your async task in each rotation ( config change ) then in your manifest file

> android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

```
<activity
            android:name="com.app.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
```

OR

When you use dinamic fragments, you must use a frame layout, and put the fragment inside it.

```
 <com.myproyect.TopMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <!-- this was the problem
    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.myproyect.HomeFragment"
        android:layout_below="@id/menu"
    />  -->

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_below="@id/menu"/>

    <LinearLayout
        ...
    >
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And instantiate the fragment inside the FrameLayout.

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, f);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer. I have edited my question above with an explanation of why I'm not using your first suggestion. The second method does not apply, as I am adding a UI-less fragment programmatically without a layout.